# Hide items before selected index of another combobox

Tags: c#

Basically I have two drop downs "`timeFrom`" and "`timeTo`" with exact same data which are time ranges.

00:30
01:00
01:30

When the user selects from the `timeFrom` drop down I get the index, then I want to filter the data in the `timeTo` drop down with the times greater and equal to the selected index of the 
timeFrom drop down.

I.e. User selects 23:30 from `timeFrom`, the only option available in time to will be 23:30 and 00:00

I have managed to apply a loop that removes indexes from the `timeTo` list but is there a nicer way? I have tried using Linq to set the Items property of the timeTo list and apply a filter with no prevail

Thanks

Comment: What type is the ItemSource?

Comment: Just a list of string, added into the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the selected index is SelectedIndex, what you want is this:

```
var result = source.Where((x, index) => index > SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: OK I have changed the list to now have a source and filtering the source.  I was using the Items collection in designer mode where i put the values.  Made sense to change it to the source

Comment: @CR41G14 What's the problem?